# Storing values android

Tags: java, android

This is kind of 2-sided question, because I should make one-time login, THAT saves data/values, so that the they can be used in another class, and even another class.

But, data should ne saved, so that everytime user comes to the app and skips the login, the values are the same as the user set on the first time....

My login contains age, height, Wright, name (just a simple login)

I have asked a lot, but I hope that someone could answer;).

Comment: search for examples about `sharedpreference login`

Comment: share your login implementation first.. show us the code..!!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Check it now i added my login details

Comment: Have you created any project?? you have some code ?? or just asking to us to create a demo for you??

Comment: No... just chill out bro I am asking for tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class provided in the Android SDK.

Here is a basic example:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

  String USERNAME = "James"
  int AGE = 24;
  int HEIGHT = 180;
  int WEIGHT = 65;

  editor.putString("username", USERNAME);
  editor.putInt("age", AGE);
  editor.putInt("height", HEIGHT);
  editor.putInt("weight", WEIGHT);
  editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, Bob and Draken, for your suggestions. I have improved the answer accordingly.

Comment: Now this is a useful answer. It would be even more useful if you'd also show how to retrieve the values from the stored settings.